# How to use Recommended Fit API for an entity with multiple planning variables?

Tags: timefold

I'm trying to implement the Recommended Fit API in my Timefold project which is a modified version of the maintenance scheduling template.

My planning entity 'Job' has multiple Planning Variables: Crew and startDate and a Shadow Variable endDate.
When a Job is not initialized, these values equal to *null*.

Now what I've tried with the Recommended Fit API is to return a list of startDate's, which leaves the Crew at *null*. Trying it the other way around works exactly vice versa. Returning the entire entity leaves all values at *null* as expected from the documentation on Timefold's website.

I'm pretty new to planning and Java in general, so any help / explanation is appreciated! Thanks.

solverConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
  <!-- Define the model -->
  <solutionClass>nl.heijmans.teamplanning.domain.Teamplanning</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>nl.heijmans.teamplanning.domain.Opdracht</entityClass>

  <!-- Define the score function -->
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>nl.heijmans.teamplanning.solver.TeamplanningConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <!-- Configure the optimization algorithms -->
  <termination>
    <spentLimit>PT30S</spentLimit>
  </termination>

  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>

  <localSearch>
<!-- <localSearchType>HILL_CLIMBING</localSearchType> -->
</localSearch>

</solver>
```

Call to Recommended Fit API:

```
@GET
@Path("opdracht/proposition")
// @Transactional
public List<RecommendedFit<LocalDateTime, HardMediumSoftLongScore>> fetch(@QueryParam("id") Long id) {
    
    // Check if corresponding opdracht exists and get it
    Opdracht entity = opdrachtRepository.findById(id);
    if(entity == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    
    Teamplanning solution = findById(SINGLETON_SCHEDULE_ID);
    List<RecommendedFit<LocalDateTime, HardMediumSoftLongScore>> recommendations =
    solutionManager.recommendFit(solution, entity, Opdracht::getStartDate);
    
    return recommendations;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Specifically, I'm interested in seeing the solver config that you use. Also, I'm interested in seeing how you call the API.

Comment: Hi Lukáš, thanks for your response, I edited my question to add the solver config and my call to the API. My full code is also available on Github: https://github.com/zwarenelle/archangel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to returning two things from a single method call. This is more of a Java question than a [Timefold Solver](https://timefold.ai/) question, but it's related enough.

Start with creating a custom carrier type for the information you need. In this case, it can be a simple Java record:

```
public record Pair(Crew crew, LocalDate startDate) {}
```

Once you have that, you can call the Recommended Fit API like so:

```
List<RecommendedFit<Pair, HardMediumSoftLongScore>> recommendations =
    solutionManager.recommendFit(solution, entity,
        entity -> new Pair(entity.getCrew(), entity.getStartDate()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see how it's indeed more of a Java problem now. This works wonders :)

Comment: Happy to help! I took a quick look at your constraints and there is one - resourceCheck - where you abandoned incremental calculation and turned to iterative processing of collections. This is a very common anti-pattern and if your data sets ever get big enough, your performance will suffer because of this.

Comment: I'll take a look at that! My data set will definitely get big in the future so it's a must. I created the resourceCheck constraint by laying out the steps in SQL first, in order to understand what it would consist of for myself. Later turning it into Java code. Thanks for your feedback.